# Can we write any batch for updating all reports with new record type

Tags: reporting, custom-report-type

We have an requrirement where we have changed the master details relationship to lookup. Hence around 1000 reports are getting effected. We have created new custom record type for the new relationship name.

Can instead of doing manually updation of all reports with new record type can there be any better solution like any automatic features or any batch.

All suggestions are welcome.

When we connect through force.com IDE we got something like..

```
*:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ReportType xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <baseObject>Account</baseObject>
    <category>accounts</category>
    <deployed>true</deployed>
    <description>Accounts and Groups</description>.....*
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Salesforce IDE on Eclipse or MavensMate to download all report and then replace `reportType` in all metadata files. Depending on complexity of the reports, some fields can be not available or have slightly different API names, so you'd have to tweak them. The best way is to recreate some of the reports with a new `reportType` and look at their metadata to do another replacements.

Comment: We are not getting report type in meta data,.please advice

Comment: When you pull the report, it's metadata is stored in the file with '.report' extension. `reportType` can be found at the end of the file: `<reportType>Opportunity@Opportunity.Component_Mgt_Team__c</reportType>
    <scope>organization</scope>`

Comment: obsolete reports done have there data in metadata.. please advice

Comment: Thanks Oleksiy.We have changed master detail relationship to lookup and we want to update report type with new custom reprot type we have created...Instead of doing it manually updation in reports we are looking for best approach

Comment: I do get what you did. Do you have a copies of old reports metadata? Or probably the old type reports can be found in sandbox?

Comment: Thanks Oleksiy, let me check if i am getting what are you saying

Comment: HI Oleksiy, Please see in the question i have udpated what i have got from IDE..Please advice..thanks

Comment: You have to pull `Reports`, not `Report Types`

Comment: Thanks Oleksiy.. I understand now..I can see report types in reports..So what that means if we have change master details to lookup then just updating reporttypes to new custom name we can update all reports..Please correct me if i am wrong..

Comment: yes, indeed ...

Comment: Hi Oleksiy..i am confused with the nomenclature used by salesforce for example for old report type in metadata name is :<reportType>OpportunityCustomEntity$Plan__c</reportType>...While in salesforce we have Opportunities_with_Plans....

Comment: How would it map to our new reportype name whose salsforce name is Opportunities_with_Plans_Custom

Comment: I'd recommend to recreate a few reports with a new `Report Type` and pull them as well - this would allow you to get the correct name. As I mentioned previously, depending on the type and complexity of the report, it might be not just a simple Report Type replacement - some fields can be not available or have different names from standard Report Types. But you have to do a global replacement for the Report Types you know won't be available and try to deploy them - will see what other errors you get. I'm just saying this is possible - we migrated from Opportunity object to Custom the same way.