# How to get report type id

Tags: custom-report-type

Is there any way we can get report type id, either through query or anyother way.
We would like to change report type to another one.
Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we write any batch for updating all reports with new record type](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/129594/can-we-write-any-batch-for-updating-all-reports-with-new-record-type)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open - while the linked post answers a portion of OP's question, they are not duplicate questions.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to retrieve `reportType` is through Metadata API, which is described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_reporttype.htm)

If you would like to update the current report with new `reportType`, you have to use Metadata API as well, described [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_report.htm)

If you would like to do it within the Salesforce platform, you can use `Apex Wrapper for the Salesforce Metadata API`, which is available [here](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) on GitHub.

Comment: Thanks Adrain, i was trying with apporach where i have fetched all metadata through force.com ide..now i am confused with the nomenclature used by salesforce for example for old report type in metadata name is :<reportType>OpportunityCustomEntity$Plan__c</reportType>...While in salesforce we have Opportunities_with_Plans...

Comment: How would it map to our new reportype name whose salsforce name is Opportunities_with_Plans_Custom

Answer (score 0):

You cannot retreive report type from Soql query.Here is the idea exchange [Link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZqOfAAK) @David Mycka